Is it possible to disabable rtl layout change for a specifique component
I'm using i18n ltr and rtl layout and when I change to rtl layout, i want one specific component to stay in ltr mode. I don't want it to change place at all. Here is the component:
 <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: "400"}}>{item.price}</Text>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "300",
                        marginLeft: 4,
                        marginTop: 4
                    }}>{item.currencyCode}</Text>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontWeight: "300",
                        marginLeft: 1,
                        marginTop: 4,
                        textTransform: 'lowercase'
                    }}>/ {item.uom}</Text>
                </View>

Is there a way to disallow the layout changes for this specific view? In the ltr layout, I have the product price, currency and uom. If I change the layout to rtl, I get the uom first, then the currency and then the product name which is no good
Here's my i18n config
import i18n, {LanguageDetectorAsyncModule} from 'i18next';
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
import en from './locales/en/translation.json';
import fr from './locales/fr/translation.json';
import ar from './locales/ar/translation.json';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const resources = {
    en: {translation: en},
    ar: {translation: ar},
    fr: {translation: fr},
};

const languageCodeKey = "languageCode";

const languageDetector: LanguageDetectorAsyncModule = {
    type: 'languageDetector',
    async: true,
    // @ts-ignore
    detect: async (callback: (language: string) => void): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            // If not null in the async storage, return it
            const languageCode = await AsyncStorage.getItem(languageCodeKey);
            if (languageCode) {
                return callback(languageCode);
            }
            // Return the device's default language or fallback to Arabic
            const defaultLanguageCode = Localization.getLocales()[0]?.languageCode || 'ar';
            return callback(defaultLanguageCode);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error detecting language:', error);
            callback('ar');
        }
    },
    init: () => {
    },
    cacheUserLanguage: async (languageCode: string) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(languageCodeKey, languageCode);
            const isRTL = i18n.language === 'ar';
            I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
            I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);
        } catch
            (error) {
            console.error('Error caching language:', error);
        }
    }
};

i18n
    .use(languageDetector)
    .init({
        compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
        resources,
        fallbackLng: 'ar',
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        },
    })
    .then(() => {
        const isRTL = i18n.language === 'ar';
        I18nManager.forceRTL(isRTL);
        I18nManager.allowRTL(isRTL);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(`Error ${error}`));

export default i18n;

